# Creating classes, constructors and methods

Tags: java

I've received a homework assignment to create classes defined in all certain ways.
I was wondering if anyone knows about a good site\tutorials that can help me understand better what exactly are classes methods and constructors.

Comment: http://www.google.co.in/search?q=Classes+and+Objects&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=com.yahoo:en-US:official&client=firefox <-- click for magic.

Comment: I like the Oracle tutorials the most - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'Thinking in Java' is really good to understand all those concepts.